# Passing Chart Series from Controller to Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am u sing `asp.net mvc 4` and placed a chart on view. i want to load its series from `controller`. how can i do that ? please can anyone explain it with piece of code.

**Index View**

```
@{
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Chart Title")
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Views",
        xValue: new[] {  "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wendesday", "Thursday", "Friday" },
        yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Downloads",
        xValue: new[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wendesday", "Thursday", "Friday" },
        yValues: new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" })

        .Write();
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely possible. Let's start by creating a new view model to represent the chart data.

```
public class ChartSeriesData
{
    public string[] XValues { set; get; }
    public string[] YValues { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}

public class MyChartData
{
    public List<ChartSeriesData> Series { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

And in your Action method, create an object if the `MyChartData` class, Set the different property values and send it to the view.

```
public ActionResult MyChart()
{
    var vm= new MyChartData { Name = "MyChartTitle",Series = new List<ChartSeriesData>()};
    vm.Series.Add(new ChartSeriesData
    {
        Name = "View",
        XValues = new[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wendesday", "Thursday", "Friday" },
        YValues = new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" }}
    );

    vm.Series.Add(new ChartSeriesData
    {
        Name = "Downloads",
        XValues = new[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wendesday", "Thursday", "Friday" },
        YValues = new[] { "1", "2", "6", "5", "3" }
    });
    return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your view ,which is strongly typed to a our `MyChartData` view model, we will iterate through the Series property and call the `AddSeries` method.

```
@model ReplaceWithYourNameSpaceHere.MyChartData
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle(Model.Name);

    foreach (var item in Model.Series)
    {
        myChart.AddSeries(name: item.Name, xValue: item.XValues, yValues: item.YValues);
    }

    myChart.Write();
}
```

If you want to include the chart in another razor view, you can use an image tag and set the `src` attribute value to MyChart action method.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("MyChart","Home")" alt="Some alt text" />
```

Assuming `MyChart` action method exists in `HomeController`.