# Display Chart in .cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been using Stack Overflow pretty heavily to implement the Chart Control using C#

```
public class ASPChartPartialViewController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private void CreateChart()
        {
            Chart myChart = new Chart();

            //Create a new series for the chart
            var series = new Series
            {
                Name = "Test Series",
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
                IsVisibleInLegend = true,
                IsXValueIndexed = true,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
            };

            //Bind the data to the new series
            series.Points.DataBindXY(new[] { 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004 }, new[] { 100, 200, 90, 150 });

            //Add the series to the chart
            myChart.Series.Add(series);
        }
    }
```

This is the controller class I'm using to start. The question is, how do I display this in the .cshtml view? MSDN documentation isn't really giving me much help with this.

Comment: The Chart class from System.Web.Helpers namespace [does not have a parameter less constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.chart.chart(v=vs.111).aspx). Are you using a different Chart class ?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946950/passing-chart-series-from-controller-to-razor-view). It might help you

Comment: Every example I see (http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart) involves putting the chart initialization directly in the markup, like an HTML helper method call.  Is there a reason you're putting it in the controller?  Are you following a different example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ASP.net chart controll you have to make sure that in your controller you return the chart as the FileContentResult so the implementation would be something like

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(GetChart().FileContents);
        }
  public FileContentResult GetChart()
    {
     Chart myChart = new Chart();
    ///when you setup your chart you can 
    myChart.ToWebImage(format: "png");
    return new FileContentResult(myChart.GetBytes(), myChart.ImageFormat);

    }
```

in the view part you can try

```
@model  byte[]

<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Model)))" alt="" />
```