# Pass values to Script to change a chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So i have this chart:

```
$(function () {
window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title:{
            text: "Evolução do seu saldo "
        },
        axisX:{
            title: "Data",
            titleFontColor: "green",
            titleFontWeight: "bold"
        },
        axisY:{
            title: "Saldo",
            titleFontWeight: "bold",
            titleFontColor: "green"
        },
        data: [
        {
            // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
            color: "green",
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: 10, y: 10 },
                { x: 20, y: 12 },
                { x: 30, y: 8 },
                { x: 40, y: 14 },
                { x: 50, y: 6 },
                { x: 60, y: 24 },
                { x: 70, y: -4 },
                { x: 80, y: 10 }
            ]
        }
        ]
    });
    chart.render();
}
});
```

What i want to do is to pass values from my database in the controller and change the chart values on x and y, but i have no idea about how can i pass the values from the controller directly to the script, cause i want that the chart initially has the values defined in the database to the x and y how can i solve it?

Ps: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you add your entire `view`? In MVC, you can use `@Model` in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to create an endpoint which returns this data in json format. 
Let's start by creating a view model which represents the data you want

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string title { set; get; }
    public Axis axisX { set; get; }
    public Axis axisY { set; get; }
    public Data data { set; get; }
}

public class Axis
{
    public string title { set; get; }
    public string titleFontColor { set; get; }
}
public class Data
{
    public string color { set; get; }
    public List<DataPoint> data { set; get; }
}

public class DataPoint
{
    public int x { set; get; }
    public int y { set; get; }
}
```

Now an create a controller and an action method in it which returns data.

```
public class ChartController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult ChartData()
  {
       var v=new ChartData();
        v.title = "Some";
        v.axisX = new Axis
        {
            title = "Title"
        };
        v.axisY = new Axis()
        {
            title = "Tes",
            titleFontColor = "red"
        };
        v.data = new Data
        {
            color = "blue",
            data = new List<DataPoint>()
            {
                new DataPoint {x = 10, y = 20},
                new DataPoint {x = 10, y = 20},
                new DataPoint {x = 10, y = 20},
                new DataPoint {x = 10, y = 20}
            }
        };
        return Json(v,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

I hard coded the values in the action method. I have no idea how your database structure or how to get that data. Your job is to use your data access code to replace the hard coded values with the real values from db table.
Now in your page's `document ready` event,call this action method and get the data, use it to render the chart

```
$(function(){
  var url = "@Url.Action("ChartData","Chart")";
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){
      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",data);
      chart.render();
  });
});
```

Comment: Very good answer, just a last question related to this, basicly the view model works like a bridge between my database and the chart right?, i should return the values got from my database to the viewModel and then work with the viewModel in my view?

Comment: View model is a strongly typed DTO's which represents the structure of data. they are simply POCO's to hold the data. you should write your code to get data from your database and set to the properties of your view model.

Comment: Here is another sample to get you going http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946950/passing-chart-series-from-controller-to-razor-view/34950881#34950881

Comment: yeah i know the purpose of it but thanks anyways, just what i need :D